# Why App Re-render When I Added AMP Character to Pug Template

Tags: pug, amp-html

I'm running NodeJS Express app, it's re-render 3 times or more when added `amp` character to pug template, my structure is:

#### app.ts

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Render index');

  res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' })
})
```

#### index.pug

```
doctype html
html(amp)
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1= message
```

My pug template has `amp` (already try ⚡ character), it show log for router `/` 3 times or more, but if I remove `amp`, the log only show 1.

So, my question is: **why it re-render 3 times or more when Pug template has `amp` character?**

How can I add `amp` character to pug template correct way to make it not re-render.

Result for AMP

[image]

Result without AMP

[image]

Comment: we are google AMP developers but do not understand the question. perhaps you can elaborate if you need help.

Comment: @JayGray I just update to clarify the issue and add question.

Comment: skip the symbol; just use `<html amp="">` or `<html amp>`

Comment: @JayGray That didn't works, just added image to question for re-rendering...

Comment: I'm not sure i can help you here. From my perspective, the issue seems to be specific to the node.js program you are using; not an AMP issue per se. Although we don's use node.js for client-side rendering (we do use it for server-side), you might look for an alternative node.js application (i've seen several; and there are vue.js applications that do the same work).